# Set Header title with NSCollectionView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, xcode7, nscollectionview

I'm working with NSCollectionView, the CollectionView has headers. I need to set an specific title for each header.

My code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: NSCollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSView {
        var view: NSView?
        if kind == NSCollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
            view = collectionView.makeSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withIdentifier: "Header", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        }
        ...
        return view!
    }
```

`Header` is a `NSCollectionViewItem`

```
import Cocoa

class Header: NSCollectionViewItem {

    var title: String!
    ...
    //Write title value in a textField
    ...
}
```

My question is: how to set the *title* value from `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`?

I need something like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean showing a title in the view of Header?

Comment: @HarryNg Yes, for example "Header 1", "Header 2"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit tricky here, I hope Apple will improve its API soon by better making use of `NSCollectionViewItem`

In fact, from the sample code `CocoaSlideCollection`, the way to show a title with variable text is by looking through the subviews of the Header View and get a reference to the `NSTextField`, then set the `stringValue`.

In action with Swift:

1. Create a `HeaderView` which is a subclass of NSView
2. Set `HeaderView` to View of Header nib
3. In `HeaderView`, implements this variable `titleTextField`

   ```
   lazy var titleTextField: NSTextField? = {
       for view in self.subviews {
           if view is NSTextField {
               return view as? NSTextField
           }
       }
       return nil
   }()
   ```
4. In `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` delegate method, do this

   ```
   let view = collectionView.makeSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withIdentifier: nibName!, forIndexPath: indexPath)
   if let view = view as? HeaderView {
       view.titleTextField?.stringValue = "Header Custom Value"
   }
   return view
   ```

Comment: The style in the answer looks awful, the code in point 3 couldn't format properly, I have to use `code` block and then `blockquote` to show it.

Comment: The style isn't the best but it works, thanks Harry!

Answer (score 1):

I use it like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: CollectionView,viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CollectionHeaderView!
{
    switch kind
    {
        case NSCollectionElementKindSectionHeader:  let contactsCollectionHeaderView                            = collectionView.makeSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind,withIdentifier:"ContactsCollectionHeader",forIndexPath:indexPath) as! ContactsCollectionHeaderView
                                                    contactsCollectionHeaderView.titleTextField?.stringValue    = self.collectionView(collectionView, titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section) ?? ""
                                                    return contactsCollectionHeaderView

        case "NSCollectionElementKindSelectionRectIndicator": return nil

        default:                                    return nil
    }
```

Be aware that currently the method signature for the delegate is wrong the returned view is optional in reality, otherwise you are not able to return special defind kinds like the rectindicator above.